# System of $n$ linear equations with $n$ variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Recently, I have been thinking about systems of equations. Typically, when there is a system of equations with n unknowns, n equations will be necessary to solve it. I was wondering if there is a proof for this. It is easy to visualize this with lines/planes when n = 2 and n = 3, but I am not sure how to generalize it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you mean *linear* equations in *real* numbers then the question should spell that out.

Comment: To prove something rigorously, you need precise definitions, so define "unknown", "equation", "typically", please! One equation $x^2_1+x^2_2+x^2_3=0$ for three real unknowns has a unique solution, for instance.

Comment: Cramer's formulas give a unique solution if you can apply them : the condition is that the main determinant is $\neq 0$. If the coefficients are random, the probability for this event is 1...

Comment: Not really true. $\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  x+y=1\\
                  2x+2y=2\\
                \end{array}
              \right.$, this system of two equations in two unknowns doesn't have unique solution. Equations have to be linearly independent. [Rouché–Capelli theorem][1] roughly speaking relates number of equations to number of solutions


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theore

Comment: I apologize if my question was not clear. Is there anyway to prove an n variable system can be solved with n equations? Specifically, I am looking at the degrees of freedom of matrix and trying to understand how the dot product and unit vector equations can be used to determine the number of degrees of freedom (http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/orthogonal/)